# ionic5: ion-content height bigger than screen

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

I've upgraded from ionic 4 to ionic 5. Now, all my ion-contents are bigger than my screen, only when running on android hardware (iOS + electron + serve are ok).

When I run `ionic serve` and I scroll to bottom of my page, result is as expected:
[image]

But if I run `ionic prepare android --prod --verbose --release`, when I scroll to bottom of the same page, I can't see my button "Afficher plus", which is out of screen (I mean, at the bottom, "behind" the bottom button bar). I can't scroll more .. :

[image]

Here is my `ionic info`:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.2 (C:\Users\joris\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.0.0\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1001.0
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.1.0
   @angular/cli                  : 10.1.0
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : not installed
   @capacitor/core : not installed

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 40 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.1
   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.0.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.4
   OS     : Windows 10
```

If somebody can help me, it would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: // I can't see my button "Afficher plus", // shouldn't it be more of a html/css question? A possible fix could be - make all your content in scrollview of some sort and  make a button permanent stick to screen bottom of screen - like facebook post or facebook messenger - so that - when you have 10000.... a lot of content, it will not disturb your button and user can easily scroll content without pressing button

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I don't think it could be more of a html/css issue, everything works fine when I serve it or when I build my app for iOS/Electron. Since my ionic 5 upgrade, it looks like if my app believes my screen height is 500px instead of 450px .. Then, my ion-content "overflows" under my screen ..

Comment: Can you reproduce it with `ionic serve` if you change "Responsive" (top left) to some Android device? And can you post the styles of the ion-content element (e.g. screenshot of the dev tools)? Lastly, is the amount that is cut off is exactly the same as the height of your header?

Comment: Thx for ur reply @thomas. If I change from "Responsive" to "Pixel 2 XL", my app style obviously changes, but there is no issue. This issue happens only when I run my app on Android (Simulator and Hardware, Android 8,9,10,10+ tested). I've tried to build my app from differents envs (MacOS 10.14, 10.15, Win10..) but nothing to do .. My ion-content elem does not have any custom style
And lasty, it could be possible that the amount that is cut off is the same as my header, all my ion-footers are completely not visible

Comment: I know that `ion-content` automatically adjusts its height based on whether there is an ion-header and/or ion-footer and depending on if there's a notch. So look at the CSS variables assigned to ion-content (I think they're called `offset-top` and `safe-area` or something similar).

Comment: Indeed, it looks like if ```ìon-content``` automatically adjusts its height ! Following your tips, I added a ```--ion-safe-area-bottom: 100px;``` to my ```variables.scss``` file. Now I'm able to see my ```ion-footers``` (and my button "Afficher plus"). Moreover, I can notice something weird, my ```ìon-footer``` does not have same height whatever my keyboard is open or close [Keyboard open](https://i.ibb.co/TMVt7Qj/Screenshot-20200910-090904-EDL.jpg) [Keyboard close](https://i.ibb.co/PzvznKP/Screenshot-20200910-090857-EDL.jpg). Do you have any idea @Thomas ? thx

Comment: I found that the amount that is cut off is exactly the height of "virtual android buttons" (Menu btn + multi task btn + back btn). When I kill my app and I relaunch it, I can see my ```ion-footer``` of my login page, but when I click on an editable field, keyboard is opening, I already can see my footer, but when I close the keyboard, my footer disappears for my login page and for all my other pages .. I don't really understand ..

Comment: You probably shouldn't change the safe area variables since that might break on devices with a different notch. `--offset-*` variables are dynamically set by `ion-content` and those seem to be wrong, but it's difficult to say without seeing some code.